# Whats the behavior for horizontal pod autoscaling using the https|request_count in?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, hpa

As you can see if the image below im using the loadbalancing.googleapis.com/https/request_count metric for my HPA defining a target of 7, on the other hand, the metric is responding with a value of 5744m, according to this [post](https://www.doit.com/autoscaling-k8s-hpa-with-google-http-s-load-balancer-rps-stackdriver-metric/) the value is in miles so i need to divide it by 1000 to get the exact value, 5744/1000 resulting in 5.7 in average, but somehow the replicas are going up even when the value is lower than the target which is 7, could you please help me to understand this behavior?

[image: Out of the hpa describe by using the command kubectl describe hpa]

Adding hpa.yaml

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa
spec:
  minReplicas: 10
  maxReplicas: 350
  metrics:
  - external:
      metricName: loadbalancing.googleapis.com|https|request_count
      targetAverageValue: "7"
    type: External
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: xxx
```

Comment: Can you post the yaml spec for your HPA as well?

Comment: Also - it looks like the HPA is currently trying to reduce the number of replicas as well.

Comment: Thanks @GariSingh i just added the hpa.yaml